# Video.js - How to add multiple audio tracks to the video.js player?

Tags: javascript, video.js, video-player, audiotrack

I am working on a project where I have to create a Video player which has multiple audio tracks. I gone through [Video.js](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-audio-tracks.html) documentation but couldn't figure it out how can I do it.

I have one .mp4 video file and different audio files I want to use as audio tracks for the video. But I am unable to figure it out how can I pass these audio files to the Video.js's player.

Is there any other library other than Video.js which can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Video.js doesn't support multiple audio tracks in this way, with separate files. Instead, you can use an HLS source which can contain multiple audio tracks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I am new to video.js, HLS and building video player, so can you explain in more details How can I implement such player? Or Can you share any resources which explains the implementation?  It will be an huge help.

Comment: Is there any other library other than Video.js which can help me with this problem?